# Action<T> vs virtual methods

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, virtual

Consider I have a game-creation framework, with a basic class called Game.

```
// Action version
public class Game 
{
    public Action<float> OnUpdate;
    public void Update(float mFrameTime) { OnUpdate.Invoke(mFrameTime); }
}

// Virtual version
public class Game 
{
    public virtual void Update(float mFrameTime) {}
}
```

---

Which one is the best approach? 
(design-wise and performance-wise)

Subscribing something to the OnUpdate action (and not inheriting the Game class), or inheriting the Game class and overriding the virtual method?

Comment: FYI the [tag:XNA] framework uses a virtual method. Personally I'd trust their judgement unless your use case is different. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on who the target audience is for the `Update` notification.  If it's for only derived classes then a `virtual` method is a fine approach.  If it's for derived classes and or arbitrary consumer then the event style pattern is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather raise events than have the `Action<T>`. This is a common pattern in .NET:

```
public class Game 
{
    public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> Update;
    protected virtual void OnUpdate(float mFrameTime) { // invoke event here }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are the advantages of raising an event instead of using an Action?

Comment: events are delegates (with access limitations). there is no dif. delegates also can have multiple subscribers (try it :). Design wise, events are typically for well, events, and plain delegates are typically for callbacks. [edit: adding emphasis that events ARE delegates - they are the exact same thing, it's an alias with some extra compiler restrictions on the access - and you get the add/remove props if you want)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the rest of your framework looks like and what you plan to do with this class. If this class simply alerts other classes that its time to update, then you'll want an event based system. If this is a base class for all games to derive from, then you'll probably want an override. No answer is 100% correct - it all depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish with your design.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I lack the knowledge to answer which of those options would be more efficient from a performance perspective, but from a design perspective I would advise overriding the Update method for the following reasons:

1. It keeps all your update logic in one spot.
2. It allows you to easily monitor the ordering of update actions.

As others have said, it depends on the purpose of the class, and I am making assumptions based on the fact that it's a 'game' class. There's no reason you couldn't implement both, with a virtual method that triggers an event. This would allow for the bulk of update code to be located centrally, with the option for elements to subscribe to the update event as needed.

When I've approached the same problem myself I've typically adopted a virtual-method approach, though I've broken down update into multiple sections for convenience and control purposes.